# How to code navigation key on instant search results?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my code:

Html :

```
<input onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" id="tsearch" class="search-query form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search here ..." name="tsearch"></input>
<div id="livesearch" style="border: 0px none;">
```

Script :

```
<script>
    function showResult(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "livesearch.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

livesearch.php is returning the results once input is provided in the search box. What changes I have to make in the above code so that it provides navigation key support on the search results and remove the results once mouse is pressed in any other area of the page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "provide navigation key support" what do you mean? Can you be more specific about the exact interaction you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all particular search results inside their own  DIV container as children of you #livesearch DIV.

Inside you keyup function use the function's event paramenter to fetch the keyCodes for arrow up and down:

- left = 37
- up = 38
- right = 39
- down = 40

Then use another function to focus the desired search result.

Hope this helps.